# Rapid Class Declaration

Tags: python

There is a list of 5 arguments. For each arg I want to declare `MyClass` instance:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        self.arg = arg

args=[1,2,3,4,5]

instanceList=[]
for arg in args:
    inst=MyClass(arg)
    instanceList.append(inst)
```

For a simple argument list like this the speed is not a factor. But in a real world the argument list can be really massive.
I wonder if a code could be designed such way that an entire list is submitted as an argument. Then a list of declared class instances is returned (a class instance per arg) gaining a speed and an efficiency.

## EDITED LATER:

Here is the test using the suggested methods:

```
import time
number=1000000
def method1():
    start=time.time()
    instanceList=[]
    for i in range(number):
        instanceList.append(MyClass(i))
    end=time.time()
    elapsed=end-start
    print 'method1: %s sec'%elapsed

def method2():
    start=time.time()
    instanceList=[MyClass(i) for i in range(number)]
    end=time.time()
    elapsed=end-start
    print 'method2: %s sec'%elapsed

def method3():
    start=time.time()
    instanceList = map(MyClass, range(number))
    end=time.time()
    elapsed=end-start
    print 'method3: %s sec'%elapsed

result=method1()
result=method2()
result=method3()
```

==========

## Result:

```
method1: 3.19368100166 sec
method2: 2.68189811707 sec
method3: 2.68188095093 sec
```

Comment: "Submit an entire list as an argument" to what?  You mean to the class, like doing `MyClass(args)`?

Comment: Whatever you do, you'll have to call the constructor `len(args)` times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for this? I'm not sure what efficiency gains you'll see.

```
instanceList = [MyClass(arg) for arg in args]
```

Or maybe even:

```
instanceList = map(MyClass, args)
```

Yes, some of these go faster than others, but not by enough to matter:

```
import timeit

setup='''
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        self.arg = arg
args=[1,2,3,4,5]
'''

action1='''
instanceList=[]
for arg in args:
    inst=MyClass(arg)
    instanceList.append(inst)
'''
action2='''instanceList=[MyClass(arg) for arg in args]'''
action3='''map(instanceList=MyClass, args)'''

print timeit.timeit(action1, setup, number=int(1e6)) / 1e6
print timeit.timeit(action2, setup, number=int(1e6)) / 1e6
print timeit.timeit(action3, setup, number=int(1e6)) / 1e6
```

Result:

```
3.40896606445e-06
3.00701594353e-06
2.68505501747e-06
```

Comment: Would this approach result to a faster code execution?

Comment: For such a simple expression, you might consider using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) rather than a list comprehension. It’s a little more concise.

Comment: Note that in Python 3, `map` is a generator, so it won't actually create any instances until you consume it. `list(map(MyClass, args))` would work like Python 2's `map`.